# Padding of divs that are to the right of a div floated left

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` with a fixed width and height floated left, and to the right of it I have two other `<div>`s.  I want to have one of the `<div>`s flush against the left-floated `<div>`'s border, and the other indented slightly.  Here is what I have at the moment...

```
<div 
    id="leftDiv"
    style="border:1px solid grey;
        width:300px;
        height:400px;
        float:left;">
        This is a left floated div with a fixed width and height
</div>

<div id="rightDiv">
    <div id="flushDiv">This should be flush.</div>
    <div id="indentDiv" style="padding:25px">This should be indented.</div>
</div>
```

But what happens with the above html is that both the `<div>`s with id's 'flushDiv' and 'indentDiv' are flush against the right side of the `<div>` with id `leftSideDiv`.

I can why this happens when I set a visible border on the `rightDiv`.  It's left side is actually flush with the left side of the `leftDiv`.  And both elements are already padded well over the 25px indentation that I want for `indentDiv`, so they both end up flush against the right side of `leftDiv`.

If I float `rightDiv` right, I get the desired indentation effect, almost.  `indentDiv` is now indented with respect to `flushDiv`, but `flushDiv` is no longer flush against the right side of `rightDiv`.

Ok, I'm not even sure I'm following myself anymore.

Does anyone understand what I'm asking and have a solution?  I'll try to sum it up:

How can I have two divs to the right of a left floated div, where one is flush agains the left floated div's right border, and the other is offset?

Comment: You could provide a demo of what you're doing on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) to give us a visual representation of what is going on and make it easier to help!

Comment: Thanks Jesse.  I kind of knew that I would be requested to provide a jfiddle.  I've never created one before so I am going to need a little time to create my first, I assume.

Comment: If I got what is written, then there is a solution http://jsfiddle.net/X6Tdg/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to accomplish? I put borders around them so you can see them... Here is an example on jsfiddle.com

http://jsfiddle.net/hawUs/

```
<div id="leftDiv" style="border:1px solid grey;width:300px;height:400px; float:left;">
    This is a left floated div with a fixed width and height
</div>

<div id="rightDiv" style=" float:left;">
  <div id="flushDiv" style="border:1px solid grey; float">This should be flush.</div>
  <div id="indentDiv" style="padding:25px;border:1px solid grey;">This should be indented.    </div>
</div> ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**Update:** You can also change the `padding` on the div `#indentDiv` to use `margin` instead. See example: http://jsfiddle.net/hawUs/1/